# php sdk facebook integration login in popup

Tags: php, ajax, facebook

I am new to Facebook application development.

I used the php-sdk  from the following url https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk.
I run the example >> example.php. it works fine. While clicking the login link it opens the Facebook site. After login it redirects to my domain.

I want to change this as 
While clicking the login the Facebook login page will be opened in popup. After login it changes the link to logout. without refreshing the page. Is is possible?

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a server-side scripting language, and as such can not perform actions such as opening a popup window.  PHP can however redirect the user to a differnt URL which is the behaviour you currently have.  In order to initiate a popup window - you will have to utilize a client-side 
language such as JavaScript.

You might want to checkout the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and specifically the [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) method.  Taken from that documentation page :

> Calling FB.login results in the JS SDK attempting to open a popup
>   window. As such, this method should only be called after a user click
>   event, otherwise the popup window will be blocked by most browsers.